# Spring MVC and JSR 303 - Manual Validation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm using Spring MVC 3 and JSR 303. I have a form backing object that has beans of different types in it.  Depending on a request parameter value, I'll have to choose a bean to validate and save. I can't use `@Valid` for validation since the bean to validate is not known until the runtime.

I was able to inject a `javax.validation.Validator` to the controller, but I'm not sure how to validate a bean with it and store any errors in a `BindingResult/Error` in a "Spring way".

I need to do it in the handler method, rather than an `initBinder` method, because of request mapping.

[edit]

The problem I'm having with `validate(Object, Errors)` is that it doesn't recognize nested beans. The bean to validate is accessed through foo.getBar().getBean(), where the foo is the form backing object. When I do `validate(foo.getBar().getBean(), errors)`, I get the following error message.

```
JSR-303 validated property 'property-name' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding
```

Has anyone done something like this before? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a guess, but have you tried

```
 errors.pushNestedPath("bar.bean"); // Path to the nested bean
 validate(foo.getBar().getBean(), errors)
 errors.popNestedPath();
```

That's how `BindingResult` is usually used for validation of the nested beans.

Answer (score 5):

Yup, the magic class you're looking for is `org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter`

This class gets a javax.validation.Validator injected into it and contains the code for, as its name implies, 'adapting' the output back into the familiar `Errors` object.  It's what's being used internally to do the processing when you put `@Valid` on a method parameter.

You can get them directly by adding an explicit `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` in your dispatcher servlet.  Just inject an instance of that as an instance of the standard Spring Validator interface and use it like you would any 'pre jsr-303' spring validation provider.

Answer (score 0):

The way the I've seen this done is to use a standard JSR-303 validator (whatever you're already injecting in) to get the violations (i.e. `Set<ConstraintViolaion<T>>`)

Then use code similar to that inside LocalValidatorFactoryBean to convert between those violations and Spring Errors:

```
public static <T> void convert(Errors errors, Collection<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations) {
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations) {
            String field = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
            FieldError fieldError = errors.getFieldError(field);
            if (fieldError == null || !fieldError.isBindingFailure()) {
                errors.rejectValue(field, violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation().annotationType()
                        .getSimpleName(), getArgumentsForConstraint(errors.getObjectName(), field, violation
                        .getConstraintDescriptor()), violation.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private static Object[] getArgumentsForConstraint(String objectName, String field,
            ConstraintDescriptor<?> descriptor) {
        List<Object> arguments = new LinkedList<Object>();
        String[] codes = new String[] { objectName + Errors.NESTED_PATH_SEPARATOR + field, field };
        arguments.add(new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable(codes, field));
        arguments.addAll(descriptor.getAttributes().values());
        return arguments.toArray(new Object[arguments.size()]);
    }
```